# In github, how can I rename a folder if neither git mv nor browser editing works?

Tags: git, github

I recently forked a repo from another user. I have named it "bagelclone". When I try to clone the repo, however, I get this error message.

```
user@lapbop MINGW64 ~
$ git clone https://github.com/user/bagleclone.git baglebagle
Cloning into 'baglebagle'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2956, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (292/292), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (2956/2956), 11.71 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.d 2664

Resolving deltas: 100% (2441/2441), done.
error: invalid path 'docs/. /doctrees/FSPL.doctree'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

When I try this I get
`user@lapbop MINGW64 ~ $ git restore --source=HEAD :/ fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Renaming the folder in the browser creates a new folder for a specific doc, and there are a hundred docs which would take forever to rename individually.

Trying to clone in the command gets:

```
$ git mv .  newfolder
fatal: bad source, source=, destination=newfolder
```

quotes don't work either:

```
$ git mv ". " newfolder
fatal: source directory is empty, source=. , destination=newfolder
(this is with cd baglebagle).
```

Not sure what to do.

Thanks so much.